# Compute derivative in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, derivative

I'm trying to compute a derivative of a pandas `Series`, i.e. `(x[n] - x[n-1]) / (t[n] - t[n-1])`.

I'm sorry if this question is a duplicate, and I know there are many similar-sounding questions already out there, but I see that most people who ask for a *derivative* actually mean a *finite difference*. To recap: a finite difference is `x[n] - x[n-1]` (not what I want). Note also that `pandas.Series.diff` computes a finite difference, and the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html) does not claim to compute a derivative.

Here is an example:

```
>>> s = pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 4, 7])
>>> s.diff() / np.gradient(s.index)
1         NaN
2    0.666667
4    0.400000
7    0.333333
dtype: float64
```

Is there no single function call that does this? I don't want to resample, either -- that's overkill.

Note that:

- `np.diff` doesn't work, because its output is shorter than its input
- `Index` doesn't have a method like `Series.diff`

Comment: `Index` can be treated like a Series with some extra steps: `s.index.to_series().diff()`

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to compute a derivative of a pandas Series, i.e. `(x[n] - x[n-1]) / (t[n] - t[n-1])`.

This *is* the finite difference of the column divided by the finite difference of the index.

e.g.

```py
>>> s = pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 4, 7])
>>> s.diff() / s.index.to_series().diff()
1         NaN
2    1.000000
4    0.500000
7    0.333333
dtype: float64
```

Note that this will give you slightly different answers than the solution using np.gradient(). np.gradient() uses a two-sided approximation for the derivative. [Documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.gradient.html)

Here's an example showing that np.gradient() isn't just `t[n] - t[n-1]`. It takes both the previous and next element into account when finding the approximation to the derivative.

```py
>>> np.gradient([1, 2, 1000])
array([  1. , 499.5, 998. ])
```

Comment: Everything you said sounds correct. Maybe I'm being a perfectionist, but I was hoping for something more concise.

Comment: This is the kind of thing where what you want is not directly possible without making some assumptions. In this case, we assume that the slope at each point is equal to the slope between the previous point and the current point. IMO, it's better for Pandas to provide the tools to make those assumptions than to make assumptions on your behalf, because those assumptions won't be right in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the best way to do this kind of very specific operation is to leverage fundamentals of pandas and just write it yourself:

```py
(
 pd.DataFrame({'x':[1, 2, 3, 4], 't':[1, 2, 4, 7]})
 .assign(xnm1=lambda d: d.x.shift(-1), 
         tnm1=lambda d: d.t.shift(-1))
 .pipe(lambda d: (d.x - d.xnm1) / (d.t - d.tnm1))
 )
```